# Angular JS: "Select All" options of "multi-select select box"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, multi-select

I have created a multiselect select box using Angular JS: below is the code for the same:

**JS:**

```
$scope.foobars = [{
    'foobar_id': 'foobar01',
    'name': 'foobar01',
}, {
    'foobar_id': 'foobar02',
    'name': 'foobar02',
}, {
    'foobar_id': 'foobar03',
    'name': 'foobar03',
}, {
    'foobar_id': 'foobar04',
    'name': 'foobar04',
}, {
    'foobar_id': 'foobar05',
    'name': 'foobar05',
}];
```

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="5" id="selFooBar" ng-model="foobarName" ng-options="medcenter as medcenter.name for medcenter in medcenters track by medcenter.medcenter_id">
    <option selected="selected">Select All</option>
</select>
```

And the output is :

[image]

Question 1: Why am I not getting the default option "Select All" in the list? And How do I get that?

Question 2: How can I Select All optiions on click of "First Option : Select All"??

Please suggest!

Comment: Angular doesn't support default option with `<select multiple>`. I suppose you could generate the options with `ng-repeat` and select all in `ng-change`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the `<option>` in the `<select>` element before you add the `ng-options` you'll have to use transclusion. the `ng-options` directive doesn't use transclusion, but you can create a custom directive that does. You can do that by utilizing `transcludeFn` in the directive post compile function:

```
compile: function(element,attrs) {
  return {
    post: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){
      transcludeFn(function(clone, scope) {
        // prepend the transcluded content to the select
        element.prepend(clone);
        // set the onclick of the clone to call the selectAll function
        clone.bind('click', function(){
          clone.scope().$parent.selectAll();
          scope.$apply();
        })
      });
    }
  }
},
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.selectAll = function() {
    $scope.selectedValues = $scope.values;
  }
}
```

Then you can set the `selectedValues` to all possible `values` on the scope, whether that's isolate or inherited. In the following plnkr example it's isolated. On click the Select All option will select the other elements. 
[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/flV2HPKbz3RKqelBvU1f?p=preview)