# How to select all options of multi select using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using jQuery to select all options of multiple select and get it's value. I want to use the same logic using angularjs.

Here's my code:

```
$scope.selectedAll = function(){
        $('#userprofile option').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('selected', true);
        });
        $scope.user.profile = $('#userprofile').val();
    }
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
 $scope.selectedAll = function() {
        $scope.$watch('selected', function(nowSelected) {
            $scope.user.profile = [];
            // if(!nowSelected){
            //     return;
            // }
            angular.forEach(nowSelected, function(val){
                $scope.user.profile.push(val.id);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your code you've tried using Angular.

Comment: You can look this answer. It might works https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099934/5515168

Comment: @JensV I've added the Angular code.